# Closed form of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\ln{n}}{n^{2k}-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

Does anyone have any information or insight on a closed form for
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\ln{n}}{n^{2k} -1}$$
Or trying to better understand this as a function of $k$? I just can't seem to do much with this. I tried expanding the log term as a Taylor series, then switch the order of summation but I couldn't see anything to do from there.

Comment: What makes you think it has a closed form though? (most of the sums don't)

Comment: I don't know that it does. I worked on it for a while, and posted here as an open question. Maybe someone had some different insight than I do on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the $k=1$ case we have
$$ -\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\log n}{n^2-1} = -\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\frac{\log n}{n^2}+\frac{\log n}{n^4}+\frac{\log n}{n^6}+\ldots\right)=\zeta'(2)+\zeta'(4)+\zeta'(6)+\ldots $$
which can be written as

$$ \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{1}{\Gamma(2m)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2m-1}\left(\log x-\psi(2m)\right)}{e^x-1}\,dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{Chi}(x)\sinh(x)-\text{Shi}(x)\cosh(x)}{e^x-1}\,dx $$
by the integral representation for the $\zeta$ function. $\text{Chi}$ and $\text{Shi}$ are the [hyperbolic cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chi.html) and the [hyperbolic sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Shi.html). As an alternative, Frullani's theorem gives 
$$ \log n = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-nx}}{x}\,dx $$
hence:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\log n}{n^2-1} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-u)\left[u+(1+u)\log(1-u)\right]}{2u^2\log u}\,du\approx 1.023 $$
and the approach can be easily extended to the $k>1$ case.

Comment: That is an amazing approach to expand this as the derivative of the zeta function. Indeed, I expected it to be involved.  I follow pretty much everything after your first step I believe. But perhaps my algebra thinking isn't working today. How exactly did you go from the first sum, to breaking it up as you did in the second sum?

Comment: @RyanGoulden: just differentiate with respect to $m$ both sides of $$\zeta(2m) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2m-1}}{\Gamma(2m)(e^x-1)}\,dx $$ then sum over $m\geq 1$.

Comment: I think my question was a bit more elementary than that. I was asking how did you go from $\frac{\log n}{n^2 -1}$ to $\frac{\log n}{n^2}+...$

Comment: @RyanGoulden: $$\frac{1}{n^2-1}=\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^4}+\ldots\right), $$ geometric series.

Comment: Ahh I believe I follow now. However, wouldn't this produce the derivatives of $\zeta(4m)$ and not $(2m)$?

Comment: Rather, $\zeta'(4m)$

Comment: @RyanGoulden: why? By the chain rule, $\frac{d}{dm}\zeta(2m) = 2\zeta'(2m)$.

Comment: Yes, but if $$\frac{1}{n^2-1}=\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^4}+\ldots\right), $$ then $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\log n}{n^2 -1} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\log n}{n^2}(\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^4}+...)$ 
Which is $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\frac{\log n}{n^4} + \frac{\log n}{n^8} +...) = \zeta'(4) + \zeta'(8)+...$ no?

Comment: @RyanGoulden: I missed a term $1+$ before and fixed it later. $\frac{\log n}{n^2-1}$ behaves like $\frac{\log n}{n^2}$ for large values of $n$, hence it is pretty obvious that the first term of its asymptotic expansion has to be $\frac{\log n}{n^2}$ and not $\frac{\log n}{n^4}$.

Comment: That makes a whole lot of sense, actually. Thank you very much for the answer!